# Simple formal definition of binary data

Tags: python, c, binary-data, formal-languages

I would like to formally describe binary data but in the simplest possible way. Something like [python's struct format string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#format-strings).

Are there any good definitions which I could use or at least take some inspiration from it?

Now I am sending binary data which are defined by C structure to server where it is parsed with python using struct module. Problem is that, I always need to change python parser if binary data changes. So I thought that I can attach some format definition of sent data.
I know I can directly use python representation but maybe there is something even smaller then this.

Comment: If smaller transmission size is what you are after, you have already achieved it if you are not sending format specifiers. Having a clearly defined protocol on both ends of the transmission helps avoid sending format specifiers. This is what almost all widely used protocols in the internet does. Changing code on both sides comes as a consequence, but ideaaly both sides should use the same code/library so you only have to change code in one place and distribute the cnages where they are needed.

Comment: "Binary data" usually means that you cannot assume anything about it. Take ascii mode in ftp for example. It may mess with whitespaces. So unless you can apply any other label, it is binary.

Comment: If you stick with Python's struct format string, perhaps you could compress the definition (but not the data) with [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). Since format strings are a limited subset of ASCII, you could pack each character into ~4.7 bits instead of the usual 8.

Comment: @Kevin I thought that I will code size of types in similar way but this approach will be even better.